# apexcharts Uncaught (in promise) Error: Element not found using vuejs2

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, apexcharts

each time i try to use apex chart with vue i keep getting this erro

```
apexcharts.common.js:13 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Element not found
```

[image]

i've tried installing it like this

```
npm i apexcharts
```

but the error still persists

i'm using vue2 please how can i go about this

Comment: You should give a `ref` to your chart container in `src/components/dum.vue`